# Can background.html be a service worker in Manifest v3?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, manifest.json, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I'm trying to upgrade from Manifest v2 to v3. However, I get service worker registration failed when I set the service_worker as background.html... why is it the case?

Comment: No it can't be. See the [migration guide](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/).

Comment: Hard to tell without looking at your code. Are you aware of the [migration instructions](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/migrating_to_service_workers/)? You might double-check that you didn't miss anything.